# Recognizing valid IP addresses having 2 or 3 components

Tags: python, regex, ip-address

I have a problem with regular expression. My intention is to return True if string containing somethin like a domain (it should be a string that is containing 2 or 3 units separated by dot).
I have written pattern like this:

```
pattern = r'([a-z]+(\.[a-z]+){1,2})'
```

And it is okay if string has 2 or three parts but it fail with longer examples like

> "www.haha.bla.pl"

I thought that `{1,2}` will make all, but it won't. Please give me some tips.

Comment: What's your input format? Are you guaranteed only one per line? Is there other text log type stuff in the input?

Comment: only things like:
        self.assertFalse(is_domain_name("www.haha.bla.pl"))
        self.assertTrue(is_domain_name("foo.tv"))
        self.assertTrue(is_domain_name("bla.pl"))
        self.assertFalse(is_domain_name("bla1.pl"))
        self.assertTrue(is_domain_name("www.bla.pl"))
        self.assertFalse(is_domain_name("foo..tv"))
        self.assertTrue(is_domain_name("z.z"))
        self.assertTrue(is_domain_name("x.y.z"))
        self.assertFalse(is_domain_name("foo.pl."))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need `regex` for this, for example you could count the length of `split`

```
def matches(s):
    return len(s.split('.')) > 2
```

Or use `count`

```
def matches(s):
    return s.count('.') >= 2
```

To handle empty strings between the `'.'` character, you can `filter` after you `split`

```
def matches(s):
    return len(list(filter(bool, s.split('.')))) > 2

>>> matches('12.34.67.98')
True
>>> matches('foo....tv')
False
>>> matches('12.345')
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Well ***if you're guaranteed that dots are never adjacent, or components empty***, you can simply count the dots, and compare if `1<= s.count('.') <= 2`

```
s = "aa.bb.cc.dd"
s.count('.')
# 3
```

Comment: This solution is not safe, it'll return 3 even if `s = "..."` which is *not* a valid domain.

Comment: @MarounMaroun did you not read the condition ***"if you're guaranteed that dots are never adjacent"*** ? Obviously it only works if that holds.

Comment: I missed that, now that you've bold it I cannot miss it :) But it's still not safe, as it can match `s = ".2.3.2"`

Comment: Ok, "if components are never empty". You get the idea. My point is simply "don't use regexes if you can get by with simple string operations".

Comment: Indeed, it's a good advice to avoid regex when they're not needed.